# submodules in ironpython

Tags: ironpython

While I'm familiar with making .net assemblies with the PythonModule assembly attribute, I'm a little curious as to how you could make submodules.  Would this be a class within a class?  i.e: if I have a class defined as an IronPython module such as:

`[assembly: PythonModule(mymodule),typeof(namespace.mymodule)]`

How could I define a submodule within `mymodule`, so that from python I could do:

`import mymodule.submodule`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's interesting, there's actually no support for this at all right now.  For the most part this has been used to implement built-in modules that exist in CPython and there's simply been no need for submodules yet.  You could have a nested static class in the class used for the module but it wouldn't import as a module - it'd show up as a type object in Python.

Comment: Hmm.  I suppose that's not necessarily a show-stopper, since import statements seem to work on nested classes, and invoking methods on them is functionally identical to invoking methods on submodules.  Thanks for your response!